# Phonegap file upload fails with error 1 (file not found) on Android

Tags: javascript, android, cordova

I have an app with the following upload javascript:

```
function take_image() {
    navigator.camera.getPicture(uploadPhoto, function(message) {alert('get picture failed');}, {
            quality: 50,
            destinationType: navigator.camera.DestinationType.FILE_URI,
            sourceType: navigator.camera.PictureSourceType.PHOTOLIBRARY
        }
    );
}

function uploadPhoto(localURI) {
    window.resolveLocalFileSystemURI(localURI, function(fileEntry) {
        myURI=fileEntry.fullPath;

        var options = new FileUploadOptions();
        options.fileKey="file";
        options.fileName=myURI.substr(myURI.lastIndexOf('/')+1);
        options.mimeType="image/jpeg";

        var params = new Object();
        params.value1 = "test";
        params.value2 = "param";
        options.params = params;
        options.chunkedMode = true;

        var ft = new FileTransfer();
        ft.upload(myURI, "http://www.mydomain.co.uk/uploadimage.php", win, fail, options);

        alert(myURI + " uploading");
    }, resolveFail);  
}
```

This sits there for about 5 minutes and fails with error code 1 (file not found) from the ft.upload call.

I have already used resolveLocalFileSystemURI to get around the weird path you get from navigator.camera.getPicture sometimes, I thought that was the issue originally. The file path to upload looks good, but it comes up file not found after having a **really** good long think about it.

Tried everything with this, the demo code simply does not work. Could it be a permissions issue?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Sort of got to the bottom of this, I was testing this on a tablet hooked on to my wifi network. When testing on a phone using a mobile data connection it worked fine, ditto when the tablet was tethered to the phone.

No idea why it gave an error 1 (file not found) rather than an error 3 (connection error) though, or indeed why it could not use my wifi connection to send the data.

Many code examples use the code above without the resolveLocalFileSystemURI element, if you keep getting error 1 try the above.